# Can I use CRT libs from pre-2015 vcredist to build in newer Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, linker, crt

I tried to build a C++ project that uses third-party libs with VS 2022. I got `unresolved external symbol printf` error. After trying linking with `legacy_stdio_definitions.lib` I got `__iob_func: identifier not found` error. According to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/073eda9b-214e-47e6-8071-f41bfa3a43fb/migrating-from-vs2010-to-vs-2017-getting-error-iobfunc-identifier-not-found?forum=vclanguage) post, the libs I'm using were built with prior VS2015 CRT libraries. Since I don't have the source code I cannot recompile them.

1. I tried installing `vcredist 2012` (I don't have VS 2012). I thought it should install the old crt libraries which have `_iob_func` definitions that I can link against. But I can't find where `vcredist 2012` was installed on my Windows 10. I searched everywhere and the only crt files I found are `ucrt` in `Windwos Kits\10`. Where does `vcredist 2012` put the libraries?
2. Can I even solve this problem using crt libraries from `vcredist 2012` which should have crt libs with defintion for `_iob_func`?
3. According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/visual-cpp-change-history-2003-2015?view=msvc-170) `The definitions of all printf and scanf functions have been built into <stdio.h>`. Does this mean that because they are inline, there are no definitions at all, because the compiler just replaced the function call with the actual code, and nothing is exported, and that's why the linker can't find any definition for `_iob_func`?

Comment: The redist only installs the dll files necessary to run a program compiled with that CRT. They are installed somewhere in the jungle under the Windows directory. If you need to link against really old libraries you may have to use an older version of Visual Studio to do it.

Comment: You may install older compiler toolchains and set them in projects settings. However I doubt the toolchain of VS2012 is available in VS2022.